# How to tell Firefox to load my page from server each time

Tags: html, firefox, caching

I'm writing a simple web page that shows the status of my server, and therefore must always be loaded from the server, and not from the cache.

How do I make it happen? I've tried

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
<title>status</title>
</head>
```

But it only works with Chrome. Any ideas about Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

This has worked for me in the past to resolve Firefox caching issues.

Source: http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/metatags.html